# How to write a description of an Extension?

Tags: swift, extension-methods

I want know please how we can do to write a description of our extension on the window which appear and where we can see note about it?

Example here of what I want to reproduce for my extension:

[image: Existing method]

And here my extension:

[image: New extension]

In advance thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Hi and sorry I found the answer so i share it.

You have in the exception to write your description after '///' (without quotes like on screenshot attached below) :

[image]

Thank you,

Comment: There are a lot of ways you can write documentation markup for your Swift API. That's one of them, and you can extend it with parameter labels (well, for functions) and lots of other stuff. See Apple's [Markup Formatting Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016497).